# Premanently redirect .php or .aspx to an extensionless asp.net MVC page

Tags: php, asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

thought the following was working but it turns out not to. I want to redirect the following pages for example. The original site was php then moved to aspx and now mvc.

http://www.example.com/page/one.aspx

http://www.example.com/page/one.php

to

http://www.example.com/page

The IIS Rewrite rile that I created is below but it needs tweaking.

```
<rule name="PHPToASPNET" stopProcessing="false">
<match url="(.*)\.php$" />
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
  <add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="\.axd$" />
  <add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="\.xml$" />
  <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example.com$" />
</conditions>  
<action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/{ToLower:{R:1}}" redirectType="Permanent" /
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<rule name="PHPToASPNET" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^(.*)/(.*)\.(php|aspx)$" />
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    <add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="\.axd$" />
    <add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="\.xml$" />
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example.com$" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/{ToLower:{R:1}}" redirectType="Permanent" />
```